# How do I fill the corner of an irregular shape in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

In order to simulate a freehand construction, I decorate the sides either with `random step` or with `bend right`.

But the coloring is done on the angle whose sides are straight.

How to fill a decorated angle?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}               
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
%\usetikzlibrary{topaths}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[bend right=10](0,0)coordinate(U)to (40:2)coordinate(R)to++(-30:2)coordinate(T)to cycle;
\pic[bend right=10,angle radius=6mm,fill=blue!60]{angle =T--U--R};
\draw[densely dotted](R)--(U)--(T);
\end{tikzpicture}

\par

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={random steps,segment length=5pt,amplitude=2pt}]
\draw[decorate](0,0)coordinate(U)to (40:2)coordinate(R)to++(-30:2)coordinate(T)to cycle;
\pic[decorate,angle radius=6mm,fill=blue!60]{angle =T--U--R};
\draw[densely dotted](R)--(U)--(T);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output with `bend right`:

[image: with bend right]

Output with `random step`:

[image: with random step]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could use `path picture`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[bend right=10]
  [path picture={\fill[blue!60](U)circle[radius=6mm];}]
  (0,0)coordinate(U)to (40:2)coordinate(R)to++(-30:2)coordinate(T)to cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={random steps,segment length=5pt,amplitude=2pt}]
\draw[decorate]
  [path picture={\fill[blue!60](U)circle[radius=6mm];}]
  (0,0)coordinate(U)to (40:2)coordinate(R)to++(-30:2)coordinate(T)to cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 26):

You could also use `draw` and `clip` on `\path` and clip a circle that has its center at `U`, like:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
 \path[draw,clip,bend right=10] (0,0) coordinate (U) to (40:2) coordinate (R) to ++(-30:2) coordinate (T) to cycle;
 \fill[blue!60] (U) circle (6mm);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\par

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={random steps,segment length=5pt,amplitude=2pt}]
\begin{scope}
 \path[draw,clip,decorate] (0,0) coordinate (U) to (40:2) coordinate (R) to ++(-30:2) coordinate (T) to cycle;
 \fill[blue!60] (U) circle (6mm);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]