# Fill under a fractal curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill, pgf-decorations, fractals

I am creating a class that I will use for my notes and, as the front page, I intended to have a fractal running through the diagonal of the page and the two parts created by the path, filled with different colors.

As you can see in the image I managed to get the fractal but the fill does not properly work. I have tried different approaches: using `\filldraw` while creating the fractal, using `path picture` as shown in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433859/) question and answer, clipping and more but none of them gave different results than what you can see in the following picture.

[image: wrong result]

This picture was created by the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \fill[blue] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
  \filldraw[fill=red,decoration=Koch curve type 2,draw=white,very thick]
    decorate {
      decorate {
        decorate {
          (current page.north west) --
          (current page.south east)
        }
      }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am then trying to understand how I can properly achieve what I want. What options are there?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Does replacing the last `};` by `} -- (current page.south west) -- cycle;` do what you want?

Comment: Yes, for the most part. Thanks a bunch, that was so easy! The only problem now is that there's a white (the draw color) line all on the bottom and left side of the document. To avoid that I would have to have 2 calls: one `\fill` with the coordinates you gave me and one `\draw` with only the diagonal. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: @gjkf I do not get the bottom left white line you mention when I compile your document.

Comment: You can see it [here](https://imgur.com/a/4A4J7b4). Of course you have to add Phelype's correction to the code to actually make the output I just gave you.

Comment: The white line is the draw. You can use `\fill[fill=red,decoration=Koch curve type 2]` with Phelype's modification and then `draw[decoration=Koch curve type 2,draw=white,very thick] ...` with our original path. Of course you can do it in one path, too, if you either clip or just go beyond the page boundaries without clipping. Then you need to replace `;` in your code by `-- ++ (0,-1) -| ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=1cm]current page.north west);`.

Comment: Got it, thanks as always :) I will answer my own question with the modified code.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Phelype Oleinik in the comments, here's the fixed code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \fill[blue] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
  \fill[fill=red,decoration=Koch curve type 2,very thick]
    decorate {
      decorate {
        decorate {
          (current page.north west) --
          (current page.south east)
        }
      }
    } -- (current page.south west) -- cycle;
  \draw[draw=white,decoration=Koch curve type 2,very thick]
    decorate {
      decorate {
        decorate {
          (current page.north west) --
          (current page.south east)
        }
      }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess you can drop the `very thick` in the first path, see [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533119/fill-under-a-fractal-curve#comment1348230_533119).